# How to make an application keep watching for any added file in a directory and execute it, then wait for another new file and repeat the process

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to keep my python script watching a directory for any new file, so that my script can execute that added file. I don't want to strain my CPU with a **while loop** that keeps on running the script checking at each and every while loop cycle straining the CPU, on the other hand, the **sleep function** only limits the script to run after a designated time, thus the sleep function is not flexible to new changes, it runs on specific intervals hence not efficient.

Is there a method using the sleep function that **waits until** a certain file is added, then **triggers** the script to run instantly without exiting the script.

As I mentioned above, when it runs this new added file(the code for running the latest added file I already have it, I made use of the **os.stat function** which allows me to pick the latest file and store it in a list), I want to keep the script watching without exiting, that is to say it will be in a sleep mode, to reduce CPU usage, and is only triggered again when a new file is in the directory.

How best can I attack this **trigger mechanism** without straining CPU with the continuously running while loop and also without using the inflexible sleep function which only checks for changes after certain intervals.

I want the script to be highly autonomous, that is to say, it's only activated when a new file is added and go back to sleep again when done processing, then wakes up(is triggered) when a new file is detected in the directory.

Regards Wisdom.

Comment: Tags are for what your question is about - nothing in your question pertains to "tensorflow",  "artificial-intelligence",  "dcmtk" or "orthanc-server" so I removed them. Check out the many duplicates on SO already that helps you solve your problem. You may also want to check superuser for more OS-centric approaches - nobody tells you you need a python script to do the detection, there may be OS-centric ways to trigger a python script when a new file pops into a watched folder.

Comment: Thank you again, I used an OS-centric approach as you mentioned. I used Watchman service for Linux. It really suited my request. (Watchman – A File and Directory Watching Tool for Changes).https://www.tecmint.com/watchman-monitor-file-changes-in-linux/